# Time complexity Analysis for loop:

Tags: amortized-analysis

why is the time complexity, O(n) instead of O(nlogn)? Wouldn't you have to multiply the complexity of outer loop with that of inner loop?

```
    int fun(int n){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = n; i > 0; i /= 2)
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            count += 1;
    return count;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first iteration of the loop the inner loop covers half of n. The next iteration covers a quarter, then an eighth, and so forth.  You can represent the coefficients by the function below.  As you can see it's an infinite series that sums to one.  Thus the entire function is O(n)

[image: Infinite geometric series of 1 over 2 to the n]